# When is the correct time/day to wish someone a happy "day'?

Tags: cultural-correctness

When is the correct time/day to wish someone a happy day (birthday,  holiday etc)?  On the day,  before the day,  after part of the day is gone?  I am always thinking you have to wish someone in advance of the day because you are rooting for them to have a good day on the day in question.  If one waits until the day,  then the day or part of the day is already done?

Comment: on the actual day

Comment: 'I hope you have a happy birthday' (etc) is quite appropriate if it's Tuesday and you won't be seeing them before their birthday on Saturday.

Comment: WHAT ABOUT SENDING A WISH THE DAY BEFORE,  EVEN THOUGH YOU CAN SEND IT ON THE DAY? WHY WAIT ON THE DAY TO HOPE THAT HE/SHE WILL HAVE A HAPPY DAY?  I SUGGEST THE DAY BEFORE  OR A FEW DAYS BEFORE IS BETTER?

Answer (score 1):

If you are wishing someone a 'happy day' - you are right you would tend to do this on a special occasion, e.g. a birthday, wedding, etc.

You would tend to qualify it with the day in question, for example instead of saying to someone in relation to their birthday "have a happy day", you would generally say "have a happy birthday". Similarly for wedding, you would say "have a happy wedding", (you generaly just use the holiday name, so 'wedding' doesn't feature day, so we omit the word day from the end of the sentence ; birthday has day in the word already).

For added effect, and to truly wish them the best of days you might say, "have a very happy wedding/birthday/holiday' etc.

In terms of when you would use the phrase: -

> You could say have "a very happy birthday" for instance, which would
>   imply you really want them to enjoy their birthday, in which case you
>   could say this in advance of their birthday or you could say it during
>   the birthday (for example if you were leaving them at some point
>   during the day).

If you are saying it during the event, you would generally say this only if you were not planning to see them again during the day.

A related idiom is to generally wish someone a nice day.

You can wish someone a nice day at any time during the day.

In common usage in this context, day is meant to mean the portion of day that has sunlight. i.e.

**Day**

> 2. the light of day; daylight:
>      [see here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/day)

see below

**Have a nice day**

> These expressions have become synonymous with a polite farewell. The
>   first originated about 1920 but, like the variants, became widespread
>   only after 1950.

ref: [free dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+nice+day)

So for instance you could say to a loved one as they leave the house in the morning "have a nice day" - meaning have a nice day today. Or you could say to someone you bump into on your way to work before you leave them to go about your day, "have a nice day" meaning exactly the same thing.

You could say to a colleague at work during the day, after lunch, "have a nice day" meaning 'have a nice end to your day' - idiomatically you would just say "have a nice day", and not "have a nice end to your day".

Similarly in your birthday example, in the middle of the day, you could still say "have a happy day" or "have a happy birthday" even though the greater part of the day may already have elapsed, meaning essentially 'enjoy the rest of your day'.

If the day had passed, then you are in the territory of evening, (i.e. no daylight hours, or the point between daylight and the sun going down - there is no strict meaning in terms of what time of the day evening starts and 'daytime' ends).

In which case you might say, "enjoy the end of your birthday" ; or if you are using it outside of the holiday context, "have a nice evening".

**evening**

> 1.the latter part of the day and early part of the night. 
>   2.the period from sunset to bedtime:

ref: [freeonline dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/evening?s=t)

Answer (score 0):

Preferably as a part of your greeting to them on the day of their birthday.

If know you won't see them on the day of their birthday, you include it in your last farewell before their birthday.

If you miss it and did not have a chance to do it before, you wish them a belated birthday at the earliest opportunity. i.e. in your next greeting.